# How many requests info jmeter can write in external file with failed request information?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In my load test i have configured to store failed request in external file so my question how many request jmeter can store external file ???

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using "Save Responses to a file" OR "View Results Tree or any other listener" OR BeanShell Sampler to save the results to a file in JMeter.

In any case, it depends on the data volume you are saving in the file. If the system has HDD then, I don't think JMeter will become the bottleneck instead disk IO will reach 100%. In any case or combination, just run a few tests and monitor the "disk IO", note the point where it reaches to 100% that way you will come to a point where JMeter can write the pass or fail response to a file successfully, beyond this point you need to use another machine.

Comment: Okay thanks Abshishek . how can i check disk IO Note ?

Comment: Cool. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves the problem. :)